# How to make vertically responsive element based on the height of window?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have input with set height and width of it in the center of the site (imagine Google) and need its position to be vertically responsive based on the height of the browser window. I was looking for a solution, but couldn't find it.

```css
input {
  max-height:4em;
  max-width: 25em;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Set the height on 50%, and the margin-top to minus the height of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use CSS3 `translateY` like this..

```
input {
  max-height:4em;
  max-width: 25em;   
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/94MsX6EnaO

Comment: This method can cause elements to be blurry due to the element being placed on a “half pixel”.

Answer (score -1):

Make the element `position:absolute` with a `top:50%`
Set a `height`, and a minus `margin-top` which should be 50% of the height.

**How?**
The `top:50%` will push the element top to `50%`. But since you want the middle of the element to be in the middle and not the top, you use a negative `margin-top` to pull the element up the half of it's height.

HTML

```
<div>
  MIDDLE ME
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height:30px;
    top:50%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-15px;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bpa6qgu6/

More detailed: http://jsfiddle.net/bpa6qgu6/1/

Another solution is using jQuery's innerHeight() to set the margin-top;